# Terraform aws_api_gateway_stage resource creation with method setting HttpMethod="*"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

I’m using terraform version 13.3. While creating an aws_api_gateway_stage resource I want to provide a method setting for all of my methods. I was following this [aws-doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-httpmethod). I can see there is an attribute named `HttpMethod` which can be provided as a “*” wildcard.So that setting can be applied to all Http Method types. But I am not able to find the corresponding attribute in terraform resource

Answer (score 0):

It's not an attribute that Terraform natively supports. If your config won't work with the default value, then you might need to use a provisioner to make an AWS API call after the resource is created.